# Proving or disproving there is a sum of these digits to 100

Tags: combinatorics

I am shown that the sum $41+20+3+5+6+7+8+9=99$ and the sum uses each digit precisely once.  I am asked to prove or disprove the possibility of a sum using each digit precisely once which results in $100$.  I guess I want to prove that any permutation of the digits cannot increase the quantity by $1$.

Clearly any permutation of the ones-digits simply keeps the quantity fixed.  Also clearly we cannot use any $3$-digit number and we cannot have all one-digit numbers, and we cannot have more than $3$ two-digit numbers.

If we just focus on permuting but not having more or fewer $2$-digit numbers, then we need to cycle $0,1,3,5,\cdots,9$ into one of the $2$-digit numbers and swap so that either with a single swap we increase the amount by $1$, or with both swaps we increase the amount by $1$.

$\cdots$

This seems like a lot of ad hoc sort of breaking into cases, and I don't feel like I'm learning anything by trying to solve it this way.  Am I missing something important?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No matter how you permute the digits and break up the summands, their total [digit sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digit_sum) will always equal $0$ modulo $3$. Since $100$ is not divisible by $3$, there is no such way to sum them to $100$.

Comment: What is the digit sum of a sum of a sum?  For instance, is the digit sum of 12+99 equal to 1+2+9+9=21 or is it the digit sum of 111 which is 3?  And is it a theorem that a number is always congruent mod 3 to its digit sum?

Comment: @Addem Yes, it is a theorem. In fact, we can iteratively take digit sums until we get a single digit, called the digital root. See Wikipedia for more details (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_root).